# not able to compare a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jsp

Here is my javascript function

```
function onload(){
   var calMaxAmtStatus='<%=request.getAttribute("calMaxAmountStatus") %>'; 
    alert(calMaxAmtStatus);        
    if (typeof(calMaxAmtStatus) != 'undefined' && calMaxAmtStatus != null){
    document.forms[0].status.value=calMaxAmtStatus;  
    }
```

i am getting

```
request.getAttribute("calMaxAmountStatus")
```

value in some cases
i want to set the value to a field whenever it is not null or empty string.

here's what i did till now
i have printed `calMaxAmtStatus` it gave me string as result
but when i tried to compare it with not null like here  `calMaxAmtStatus !=null`  it seems to be not working.

i am getting null printed in that field everytime

my question is i dont want to print anything if  `calMaxAmtStatus` variable doesn't have any value.

Comment: I think this is because you should write NULL  instead of null

Comment: @ShrikanthBuds, `calMaxAmtStatus` always has a string value, not a primitive null. Because of single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This code will never be executed: `typeof(calMaxAmtStatus) != 'undefined' && calMaxAmtStatus != null`. Because in any case you will have a string value.

In this code `var calMaxAmtStatus='<%=request.getAttribute("calMaxAmountStatus") %>'` `calMaxAmtStatus` variable always has a string value. Even if `request.getAttribute("calMaxAmountStatus")` will return `null` in java, in JavaScript It will transformed to the `"null"` value. Quoted word "null".

Try this:

```
function onload(){

   var calMaxAmtStatus='<%=request.getAttribute("calMaxAmountStatus") %>'; 

   alert(calMaxAmtStatus);  

   if (calMaxAmtStatus && calMaxAmtStatus != 'null') {

       document.forms[0].status.value=calMaxAmtStatus;  
   }
}
```

Lets analyse:

```
if (calMaxAmtStatus && calMaxAmtStatus != 'null') {

    /*
        If calMaxAmtStatus is not an empty string and 
        calMaxAmtStatus is not equal to 'null' string 
        value (NOT to null primitive type) run your code
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here I think is the quotes in your declaration

> '<%=request.getAttribute("calMaxAmountStatus") %>'

This will cause a null variable to be assigned as 'null' which means your variable is never truly undefined add to your if to check for the string value of 'null'.

> if (typeof(calMaxAmtStatus) != 'undefined' && calMaxAmtStatus != null && calMaxAmtStatus!= 'null')

Answer (score 0):

Let the test be at the server side:

```
function onload(){
   var calMaxAmtStatus= <%= request.getAttribute("calMaxAmountStatus")? "'"+request.getAttribute("calMaxAmountStatus").toString()+"'" : "null" %>; 
   alert(calMaxAmtStatus);        
   if (calMaxAmtStatus){
   document.forms[0].status.value=calMaxAmtStatus;  
}
```